# i want datagridview cell to be cleared and remain focused

Tags: vb.net

I have a Datagridview that contains 4 columns Item,Qty,Price,Amount. the user should enter the item name in the first column. i have a table  in the database that all the item names are stored. so the inserted name should be checked if its in database or not. if its not in the Database i want the  cell to be cleared like a TextBox and the focus remains in that cell. the user should not be allowed to Continue until he enters the correct item name... so far i have tried this

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
   
        connect()
        sql = "Select ProductName from Products where ProductName = '" & Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString & "' "
        objcmd = New SqlCommand(sql, objcon)
        OBJDR = objcmd.ExecuteReader
        If OBJDR.Read = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Item Name Is not in the Items list", "Item Name Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)   
                     ''clearing the cell    '    
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = ""
            '' here i want the cell to get foucus and the cursor remain like textbox
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Cells(0)
            ' DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
            Exit Sub
        End If
 End Sub
```

here is the image of my datagridview
[image: datagridview1]

[datagridview2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RpX4.jpg)

this is a datagridview that is displayed to the user as he types so he can pick item names from it.it works like a ComboBox AutoComplete.

Comment: Instead of expecting the user to know the exact name of every item, why not make that column a ComboBox column that they pick the item from?  That way they cannot chose a wrong item.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. You have an extra `End If`

Comment: i am not  expecting the user to know the exact name. i forget to mention i have a  datagridview  that only appears and displays the the names of the all  items as the user types in that cell. it suggests the items as he type. he can pick on from that datagridiew by clicking it and then the datagridview becomes invisible or he can write the exact item name. but what if he does not pick one from it or ent. i want the contents of the cell to be cleared and the cell to remain focused

Comment: i removed the extra end if. my only problem is making that cell to remain focused like we do in textboxes. until the correct item name is entered...

Answer (score -1):

Finally i got what i was looking for. I put the code in cell validating event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating
       With DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
           If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
               If Not ItemExists(.Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value) Then
                   MessageBox.Show("Item Name Is not in the Items list", "Item Name Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                   e.Cancel = True
               End If
           End If
       End With
   End Sub
```

---

```
Function ItemExists(ByVal itemname As String) As Boolean
      Dim bResult As Boolean = True

      connect()
      Sql = "Select ProductName from Products where ProductName = '" & itemname & "' "
      objcmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, objcon)
      OBJDR = objcmd.ExecuteReader
      If OBJDR.Read = False Then
          bResult = False
      End If

      Return bResult
  End Function
```